# Is there a name for this double summation identity? What is the shortest way to illustrate that it holds?

Tags: summation, alternative-proof

Say I have the following the expression:
$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{i-1} \sum\limits_{u=0}^{j} g(u)$$

By enumeration, it is easy to see that:

in the case when $j=0$ we have 
$$\sum\limits_{u=0}^{j} g(u) = g(0)$$
in the case when $j=1$ we have 
$$\sum\limits_{u=0}^{j} g(u) = g(0) + g(1) $$
in the case when $j=n$ we have
$$\sum\limits_{u=0}^{j} g(u) = g(0) + g(1) + ... g(n)$$
... and so for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, the number of $g(k)$ is precisely that of the number $j$ is reaching minus $k$ plus 1 i.e.,

$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{i-1} \sum\limits_{u=0}^{j} g(u) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{i-1} g(j) \cdot (i-j)$$

I am aware that this can be easily proven by induction. But is there a name such this identity? Or a one-liner proof for it? I am working on an article (it is a new proof for a known theorem) and a part of it involves using this identity. So I am wondering how should I demonstrate that it holds in the simplest way possible (or is this a trial fact)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It hasn´t a name, but in my opinion there is only a version of Fubinni-Cantelli's Theorem.

For a "linear proof" we have: First, for simplicity, take $n=i-1$. Thus, $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{i-1} \sum\limits_{u=0}^{j} g(u)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n} \sum\limits_{u=0}^{j} g(u)$.

Now, since $0\le j\le n$ and $0\le u\le j$, we can "iterated" the sum as putting $0\le u\le j\le n$ (such that in multiple integration) to obtain $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n} \sum\limits_{u=0}^{j} g(u)=\sum\limits_{u=0}^{n} \sum\limits_{j=u}^{n} g(u)=\sum\limits_{u=0}^{n}g(u) \sum\limits_{j=u}^{n}1=\sum\limits_{u=0}^{n}g(u)(n-u+1)$.

Finally, since $n=i-1$ we have $$\sum\limits_{u=0}^{n}g(u)(n-u+1)=\sum\limits_{u=0}^{i-1}g(u)(i-u)$$

as we desired.

Comment: Thanks! Can you provide more info regarding Fubini-Cantelli's Theorem? I did a google search but only found [the wikipedia entry for Fubini's theorem which doesn't mention about Cantelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem).

Comment: In the page that you mentioned, it appears in the middle. The geometric mean is a generalization of the area of a rectangule: Area=height\times base, But if you see the same rectangle from another point of view, the height becomes base and the base becomes height. Then, it is no matter for which side you choose to be height and which side to be base.

Comment: Ooh. I see! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It’s basically just reversing the order of summation:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\sum_{u=0}^jg(u)&=\sum_{0\le u\le j\le i-1}g(u)\\
&=\sum_{u=0}^{i-1}\sum_{j=u}^{i-1}g(u)\\
&=\sum_{u=0}^{i-1}\big((i-1)-(u-1)\big)g(u)\\
&=\sum_{u=0}^{i-1}(i-u)g(u)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Normally I’d shorten this by two steps that I’ve included here for extra clarity: I’d omit the version with the single summation, and I’d omit the penultimate line, making it a two-step calculation.